# Grouping data across midnight and performing an operation using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date, grouping, resampling

I have the following data contained in a DataFrame which is part of a custom Class, and I want to compute stats on it for night-time periods.

```
                     LAeq,T  LAFmax,T  LA90,T
Start date & time                            
2021-08-18 22:00:00    71.5      90.4    49.5
2021-08-18 22:15:00    70.6      94.0    45.7
2021-08-18 22:30:00    69.3      82.2    48.3
2021-08-18 22:45:00    70.1      89.9    46.4
2021-08-18 23:00:00    68.9      82.4    46.0
                     ...       ...     ...
2021-08-24 08:30:00    72.3      85.0    61.3
2021-08-24 08:45:00    72.9      84.6    62.2
2021-08-24 09:00:00    73.1      86.1    62.6
2021-08-24 09:15:00    72.8      86.4    61.6
2021-08-24 09:30:00    73.2      93.5    61.5
```

For example, I want to find the nth highest LAFmax, T for each given night-time period.

The night-time period typically spans 23:00 to 07:00, and I have managed to accomplish my goal using the `resample()` method as follows.

```
def compute_nth_lmax(self, n):
    nth_lmax = self.df["LAFmax,T"].between_time(self._night_start, self._day_start,
                                                                     include_start=True, include_end=False).resample(
        rule=self._night_length, offset=pd.Timedelta(self._night_start)).apply(
        lambda x: (np.sort(x))[-n] if x.size > 0 else np.nan).dropna()

    return nth_lmax
```

The problem is that resample() assumes a regular resampling, and this works fine when the night-time period is 8 hours and therefore subdivides 24 equally (as in the default case of 23:00 to 07:00), but not for an irregular night-time period (say, if I extended it to 22:00 to 07:00).

I have tried to accomplish this using `groupby()`, but had no luck.

The only thing I can think of is adding another column to label each of the rows as "Night-time 1", "Night-time 2" etc., and grouping by these, but that feels rather messy.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go with what I consider a slightly inelegant approach and create a separate column which flags the night-time periods, before processing them. Still, I managed to achieve my goal in 2 lines of code.

```
self.df["Night-time indices"] = (self.df.index - pd.Timedelta(self._day_start)).date
nth_event = self.df.sort_values(by=[col], ascending=False).between_time(self._night_start, self._day_start)[
            [col, period]].groupby(by=period).nth(n)
Out[43]: 
Night-time indices
2021-08-18    100.0
2021-08-19     96.9
2021-08-20     97.7
2021-08-21     95.5
2021-08-22    101.7
2021-08-23     92.7
2021-08-24     85.8
Name: LAFmax,T, dtype: float64
```